# VBA find function throws error

Tags: vba, excel

I cannot get this code to stop throwing the error

> 'object required'

I had to put the .Activate in front of everything and now it goes to the set cf . find then throws an error for it. I am trying to search information based of an input box then put the information from a user form into cells based on the search criteria. Please someone help. Thanks

```
Worksheets(" MthruF Schedule").Activate     
Dim Req As Variant
Req = InputBox("Please Enter Requisition Number", "Information")    

'Worksheets(" MthruF Schedule").Range("A1").Activate   

Dim FirstAddress As String, cF As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(" MthruF Schedule").Range("A1").Cells(3, 1).Activate 

    'First, define properly the Find method
    Set cF = .Find(What:=Req, _
              after:=ActiveCell, _
              LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
              LookAt:=xlPart, _
              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
              SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
              MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False)                    

    'If there is a result, keep looking with FindNext method
    If Not cF Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = cF.Address
        Do
            cF.Offset(0, 9).Value = EmpInfo.FirstName.Value & " " & EmpInfo.LastName.Value
            cF.Offset(0, 10).Value = EmpInfo.ComboBox3.Value & "/" & EmpInfo.ComboBox20.Value & "/" & EmpInfo.YearCmb.Value
            cF.Offset(0, 11).Value = EmpInfo.AgencyBox.Value
            cF.Offset(0, 12).Value = EmpInfo.AgencyName.Value
            Set cF = .FindNext(cF)
        'Look until you find again the first result
        Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If

End With
```

Comment: Does worksheet " MthruF Schedule" really have a space as first character? You can't add `.Activate` like this on the same line as `With`. Also put `Option Explicit` statement on top of the module.

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?  `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(" MthruF Schedule").Range("A1").Cells(3, 1).Activate` looks wrong.  How do you activate cells(3, 1) of a single cell range?

Comment: The error is being through at the like that is stated        Set Cf  =  .Find                   Also, Yes it has a space in front of it and this isn't all of the code.

Comment: de ja vu? Didn't I see this a couple of days ago?

Answer (score 1):

I needed to activate the sheet, not the cells in the sheet. I put the following in before my code above, to complete this long, irritating process:

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet


 Set ws = Sheets(" MthruF Schedule")

 ws.Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `with` block is being declare with `.Activate`. `.Activate` has no further methods so it doesn't know what to do with the `.Find`. If you put the `.Activate` inside your with block you will get your desired result

```
Worksheets(" MthruF Schedule").Activate

Dim Req As Variant
Req = InputBox("Please Enter Requisition Number", "Information")


'Worksheets(" MthruF Schedule").Range("A1").Activate

Dim FirstAddress As String, cF As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(" MthruF Schedule").Range("A1").Cells(3, 1)
    ' .Activate has no further objects so it is throwing the error.
    ' Put it on a separate line and it should work
    .Activate
    'First, define properly the Find method
    Set cF = .Find(What:=Req, _
    after:=ActiveCell, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False)

    'If there is a result, keep looking with FindNext method
    If Not cF Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = cF.Address
        Do
            cF.Offset(0, 9).Value = EmpInfo.FirstName.Value & " " & EmpInfo.LastName.Value
            cF.Offset(0, 10).Value = EmpInfo.ComboBox3.Value & "/" & EmpInfo.ComboBox20.Value & "/" & EmpInfo.YearCmb.Value
            cF.Offset(0, 11).Value = EmpInfo.AgencyBox.Value
            cF.Offset(0, 12).Value = EmpInfo.AgencyName.Value
            Set cF = .FindNext(cF)
            'Look until you find again the first result
        Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With
```

Comment: it would probably better to use a reference on the range returned by **Worksheets(" MthruF Schedule").Range("A1")** in stead of using Active. For instance you can define the following : **Dim r as Range** and then **set r= Worksheets(" MthruF Schedule").Range("A1")**. Inside the find replace **ActiveCell** by **r**. Also replace **With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(" MthruF Schedule").Range("A1")** by **With r**

Comment: No, it will throw an error if I do that. I had to put it outside to prevent it from throwing the error. Nothing I do works for this

Comment: Unless you have another `With` block that you haven't shown in your code that will cause an error as it isn't nested. What is your range that you're trying to use `Find` on and also are you running this code from the same workbook?